# Making doxygen work with Solidity

Tags: doxygen, solidity

I'm studying the idea of using doxygen to document `Solidity` code. `Solidity` is close enough to `C#` and other C-like languages that I can get a decent result with telling doxygen to interpret `.sol` files as a `.cs`, and writing a tool to massage the original files to conform to `C#` syntax.

The problem is that doxygen expects to work with Classes, and `Solidity` has contracts and libraries instead. The result is that in the generated documentation all the section titles links and so refer to "Classes" instead.

Is there any way I can change the HTML to have "Contract" or "Library" instead of Class, as appropriate?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of aspects in respect to this question, some thoughts:

- **input**

  - the code should be converted to a format that is understood by doxygen. Best is to do this, initially as I think it is a bit to far fetched to create a code scanner and code colorer etc. for it at this stage, by means of an `INPUT_FILTER` see the doxygen documentation.
- **output**

  - as the terms for `Solidity` are not known an approach would be to change all the words by means of a postprocesing script. This is quite cumbersome and also error prone as some words might be present in regular texts as well.
  - create a local (!) version of doxygen and modify the strings in the `translator_..` of the, natural, language that you are using and use this to generate the documentation.

Comment: Thank you, Albert. I had looked at making a filter and that seemed doable. 
But it does not fix the output. 
I had not thought of post-processing, it looks promising but as you say is error-prone. The suggestion to use a different language is actually good, but there is one problem it does not solve.


There are two constructs in Solidity that match "class", and which one to use depends on the keyword used in the source code (contract or library). Translating might not be enough to catch this. 

What I'd need is some configurable HTML template. Does Oxigen have this?